# Forms with Ajax send with multi-parameter and A href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

within the form element I send data with a href. Using the JavaScript (as defined below), it works perfectly.

I want to send the forms now with Ajax, unfortunately it does not work. Do you have a solution for me. jQuery is included on the page.

Thank You!

```
function sendData(sFm, sID, sFn, sCl) {
    var form = document.getElementById(sFm);
    form.sid.value = sID;
    form.fnc.value = sFn;
    form.cl.value = sCl;
    form.submit();
}
```

```
<a href="Javascript:sendData('myform', '2343', 'product', 'order');">Send Data</a>
```

My new Code:

```
function sendData(sFm, sID, sFn, sCl) {
    var form = $("#"+sFm);
    form.submit( function() {
        var sid = $('input[name="sid"]').val(sID);
        var fnc = $('input[name="fnc"]').val(sFn);
        var cl = $('input[name="cl"]').val(sCl);
        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: {sid: sid, fnc: fnc, cl: cl}
        }).done(function( e ) {
        });
    });
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Where's your AJAX code that you are trying?  This is a standard form submission, not an AJAX call.

Comment: see my code update pls.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function() { // for all forms, if you want specially one then use id or class selector

    var url = $(this).attr('action'); // the script where you handle the form input.
    var method = $(this).attr('method');    

    $.ajax({
           type: method,
           url: url,
           data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // handle response here
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

:) , Thanks

Just because we don't want to submit all form by ajax so we can set a data-attribute to form tag to indicate, will it should be submit by ajax or normally ,, so ,,

```
$("form").submit(function() {  ...

   if($(this).attr('data-ajax') != "true") return true;  // default hanlder

   ...
```

so If form is written like this :-

```
<form action="/dosomething" method="post" data-ajax="true">      </form>   // will be sumit by ajax

<form action="/dosomething" method="post" data-ajax="false">      </form>
```

// will be sumit by default method

Comment: I have previously assigned values to the hidden inputs. Your code NOT help me. :-(

Comment: This solution is genric, mean will work for all forms, not specific to a partiruler form ,, :)

Comment: Ok, but how can I specify my values before?

Comment: I did not understand o.O ?

Comment: see my code. I need values to pass to the inputs before.

Comment: <form id="frm" action="ajax.php" method="post" data-ajax="true"> <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="some"> <input type="hidden" name="fnc" value="some">  </form>    <a href="#" class="form_submit" data-from="frm"> Send Data </a>  $('.form_submit').on('click', function(){ var fr =   $(this).attr('data-form'); fr = '#' + fr; $(fr).submit();   return false;   });  :)  _/|\_ Done :p

Comment: ajax.php is not possible but 'data-ajax = "true" necessary?

Comment: when you will use data-ajax=true so form will be submit by ajax method, and page will not refresh, if you will not use that so whole page will refresh and form will submit, like standard way , :)

Comment: Ok, I Try later and let you know.